# Denied Sql permission while following MVC 4 tutorial / SSDT not installing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-data-tools

this is my first post on this site, which is also a last resort for me because I know the stigma against asking trivial questions on here. But this is a fairly unique problem that I can't otherwise find a solution to so here I am.

I started following along the official ASP .NET MVC 4 tutorial on Microsoft's website. Everything went smoothly until part 6, when I recieved [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNj98.png) in my IDE.

*All of the code I am using are identical to the ones in the tutorial as I have been copy+pasting every code block from tutorial pages 1-5*.

**Possible Error**

I remembered on the first page introducing MVC 4 that I would need to download a couple of packages so I could develop with MVC 4 on VS 2012. I was able to install SP1 and LocalDb, but now that I have a problem with my tutorial app, I realize now that I didn't install *SSDT for VS 2010* with the Web PI (which the article states I need). I don't know if this is the reason why it's not working, but I tried downloading it now and I get this error message:

**Possible Error > Message**

> This product did not download successfully. Downloaded file failed
>   signature validation and may have been tampered with.

I tried searching all over the interwebz for a solution, but all of the search results have been on a different error, which had to do with an expired timestamp on the signature validation. Here is the Web PI log of my failed installation: http://goo.gl/p8y5ne

Right now I am really frustrated because I feel like I searched for all of the possible solutions and since this is for my work and not just for fun, I'm really stressed out.

**Using**:

- Windows 7 operating system
- Visual Studio 2010 IDE

Comment: Have you tried a fresh SSDT install? Their blog has the details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/   You'd probably want the October 2013 release as the January 2014 release seems to be just for VS2012 IDE, not VS2010. (at least at this time)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Running Visual Studio as administrator? (right click the icon, -> run as administrator).

The error you are getting is not related to SSDT, but SSDT may cause issues later in the tutorial, and it seems as though the SSDT issue is a bad download of the installer.